# Only have specific columns appear in the total line of a pivot table

Tags: excel, vba

Is there a way in Excel to exclude some of the columns from the Total line of a summary in a Pivot Table?  I have an issue where confusion would be created as at an individual level the three columns show: baseline, current, growth but at the total level I want the average of the growth of the lines which would not relate to the other two columns.  To then show the baseline and current columns on that row would create confusion as the growth there would be unrelated to the numbers in those columns.

Thanks

As per the request below a screenshot of the tables.

The first pivot table shows all the columns, the second just the ones where I want the averages to be shown.  The other columns should be shown, but at the totals I need them to be blank as the average of the two growth columns will not be the result of the two columns next to them creating confusion.
[image]

Comment: Yes. What can be filtered in the `Pivot Table` can also be filtered in the `Pivot Chart`.

Comment: Your question is not clear. Can you post a screenshot of a pivot table and explain in context? When you say chart, do you mean a chart or a pivot table in a grid? When you say line, do you mean a line in a line chart or a row in the pivot table? You use line and column in the same breath, so it's not clear. A pivot table has a total row. I don't know what you mean by total "line". Please edit your post and add a screenshot.

Comment: Added a screenshot as requested above